# Drawing a line on an image using mouse event with OpenCV and how to move the drawn line

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

Drawing a line on an image using mouse event with OpenCV and how to move the drawn line.
what will the solution be in python and OpenCV?
currently working on microscope image processing in the project.

I am trying to draw a line on an image using a mouse event with OpenCV and I want to move the line on the image.

Comment: the `cv2.line()`  mehod will allow you to draw lines in an image. Here you have an example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-line-method/

Comment: cv2.line() I know bro but I want to draw the line on the image and move the line, if you know please suggest to me, how can i do

Comment: How you want to move it? click and drag? just making a new line that makes the previous one disappear? Make some code that draws a line where you click, then when you have that think how you want to move that line.  You need to provide the code of what you have tried for us to be able to help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37235130/3962537

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing filled polygon using mouse events in open cv using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099262/drawing-filled-polygon-using-mouse-events-in-open-cv-using-python)

Comment: you will need to not just draw the line, but keep an "object" representing the line, and then you need to implement some GUI that gives this line "handles" you can click and drag. this is a lot of work. just use a proper GUI toolkit. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for making GUIs.